# MATLAB - Limitation of Fibonacci Code

Tags: matlab

I tried to write a code for Fibonacci series  using while loop. I  wrote the following code
[after editing to 46](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2exR.jpg)

[Original code upto 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0vVl.jpg)

```
f=[1,1]; %Valid till 44 terms, for larger numbers this method can't be used
i=3;
while i<45
    fNew=f(i-1)+f(i-2);
    f=[f,fNew];
    i=i+1;

end
```

Upto 45 numbers, it works fine . Bu if I write 46 instead of 45 in the code above, I get random zeroes ( about 40 in number) followed by some random numbers. Why is it so ?

Comment: Perhaps it is just a representation issue? Try `fprintf('%i\n',f)` to see the numbers formatted "properly"

Comment: where to write above code ? out of loop or in loop ? Images have been added.

Comment: In the figure up to 46, a scaling factor of 1e+9 is mentioned. If you request only the first element `f(1)`, it will looks find.

Comment: Note that you have a scalar multiplication in the beginning of the result: `1e+09*`. The reason is what @LuisMendo wrote.

Comment: You should write the `fprintf('%i\n,f)` in the command window after running your code. you can also open `f` in the variable window.

Comment: It works. Can you please tell what was the problem and how this code resolved it ?

Comment: These are only a different ways to represent the same numbers. Because you have big numbers in the vector (with the 46 version), the default of Matlab is to represent it as lower numbers, multiplicated by a high scalar. The `fprintf` solution just show you the numbers in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with the calculation of the Fibonacci row. You only misinterpreted the graphical representation of it.

If you print a matrix, you should always check the multiplication factor at the beginning. Note that `1e+9 * 0.0000 != 0`, but `1e+9 * 0.0000 < 1e+5` By default matlab will not print the result with full resolution. You can change this with the [`format`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command, for example:

```
format longg
```

As alternative, you can print the matrix with a specified format as suggested in the comments:

```
fprintf('%i\n',f)
```

Or you can ask one element from the vector:

```
f(1) % will return allways 1
```

Note that Matlab by default tries to use a common scale factor for all elements in a printed matrix, which may not be appropriate for all elements.